# What is the best way to backup logs in Amazon S3 in real time?

Tags: linux, amazon-s3

I want to backup all my logs in Amazon S3 in real time, which tool I should use?

Comment: Have you considered http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/10/introducing-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that S3 *doesn't allow you to append* to an existing S3 object, so all of a sudden, a thousand lines from one machine's log are now a thousand S3 objects--gulp!  S3 doesn't deal well with lots of small files, and your costs will quickly skyrocket.  You could replace the object (get the existing object, add the new line, re-submit), but this is just as expensive.

So let's broaden the question some more--what if we change "real time" to be more like "about an hour old"?  Or as one might say, [when you go to rotate the logs hourly, you can rotate them into S3](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-rotate-logs-to-s3/).

To answer the question of "real time" logs, there are already multiple solutions out there, but some assembly is required.  Two great ones that spring to mind:

- [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/): Expensive, but amazing.  They do have a free tier, IIRC, but this will depend on how much data you have.
- [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/): Straight up centralized data collection that can output to S3 (by aggregating data).

Comment: How about Logstash? Is it possible to store the logs to S3 from Logstash?

Comment: It would appear to: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/s3